# How to overwrite columns value by selecting another columns in partition table in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

Hi  how to overwrite columns value by selecting same partition table in hive.

I have created table by executing below query

```
CREATE TABLE user (fname string,lname string) partitioned By (day int);
```

And i insert the data , after inserting  data into table .
I  executed  select query it looks like below:

```
AA  AA  20170201
BB  BB  20170201
CC  CC  20170201
DD  DD  20170202
EE  EE  20170203
```

As per my requirement, I want to add one more column to my table(user) ,with the help of below query I added.

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMNS ( day2 int);
```

After adding column,my table look like below

```
AA  AA  NULL    20170201
BB  BB  NULL    20170201
CC  CC  NULL    20170201
DD  DD  NULL    20170202
EE  EE  NULL    20170203
```

But I want table like.

```
AA  AA  20170201    20170202
BB  BB  20170201    20170202
CC  CC  20170201    20170202
DD  DD  20170202    20170202
EE  EE  20170203    20170203
```

So I executed below query

```
insert overwrite table user partition (day)
select
    fname,
    lname,
    day as day2,
    case 
        when day <= 20170202 then 20170202
        when day > 20170202 then day
    end as day
from user;
```

then I have executed select query like below

```
select * from user;
```

result is :

```
AA  AA  NULL    20170201
BB  BB  NULL    20170201
CC  CC  NULL    20170201
AA  AA  NULL    20170202
BB  BB  NULL    20170202
CC  CC  NULL    20170202
DD  DD  NULL    20170202
EE  EE  NULL    20170203
```

why i am getting null values.Can please let me know anything I missed out, let how to achieve this.i.e

```
   AA   AA  20170201    20170202
    BB  BB  20170201    20170202
    CC  CC  20170201    20170202
    DD  DD  20170202    20170202
    EE  EE  20170203    20170203
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Following the behaviour of partitioned Hive Table, HiVE's schema
>   definitions are maintained at partition level.So older partition may not have received schema updates.

**Detailed Query**

```
hive> drop table test_insert;
OK
hive> CREATE TABLE test_insert (fname string,lname string) partitioned By (day int);
OK
hive> insert into test_insert partition (day=20170202) values('f','l');
OK
hive> insert into test_insert partition (day=20170203) values('f','l');
OK
hive> select * from test_insert;
OK
f   l   20170202
f   l   20170203
Time taken: 0.148 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> ALTER TABLE test_insert ADD COLUMNS ( day2 int);
OK
Time taken: 0.193 seconds
hive> select * from test_insert;
OK
   f    l   NULL    20170202
   f    l   NULL    20170203
```

At this point, notice the point that **schema for partitioned table is maintained at partition level** and it's expected honour the partition schema and not table schema.

Notice the difference down in the columns here. ALTER did not change the column definitions for existing partitions.

```
  hive> describe formatted test_insert;
    OK
    # col_name              data_type               comment             

    fname                   string                                      
    lname                   string                                      
    day2                    int                                         

    # Partition Information      
    # col_name              data_type               comment             

    day                     int    

    hive> describe formatted test_insert partition (day=20170202);
    OK
    # col_name              data_type               comment             

    fname                   string                                      
    lname                   string                                      

    # Partition Information      
    # col_name              data_type               comment             

    day                     int
```

Have tweaked your above query, to create NEW partition, so that schema will be copied over from table to newly created partition.

```
 hive> insert overwrite table test_insert partition (day)
        > select
        >     fname,
        >     lname,
        >     day as day2,
        >     case 
        >         when day <= 20170202 then 19999999
        >         when day > 20170202 then day
        >     end as day
        > from test_insert;


    hive> select * from test_insert;
    OK
    f   l   20170202    19999999
    f   l   NULL    20170202
    f   l   NULL    20170203
    Time taken: 0.224 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Hope this is clear.!
If you want to change the schema for all existing partitions try below command and then Try insert.

```
ALTER TABLE test_insert  partition(day) ADD COLUMNS ( day2 string);
```